# AsyncTask Error - after the new Android SDK updates

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mapview, google-places-api

I'm trying to get Google Places connected to MapView but getting errors, it was working fine before, but the errors appeared after updating the Android libs to the latest one.

please let me know what's up with the error.

```
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at com.x.get2food.MainActivity$LoadPlaces$1.run(MainActivity.java:217)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3717)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at com.x.get2food.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:211)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at com.x.get2food.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-20 05:41:47.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20755):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Error area;

```
        // calling background Async task to load Google Places
        // After getting places from Google all the data is shown in listview
        // Fired @ onCreate()
        try{

            new LoadPlaces().execute();

        }catch(Exception e){}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load Google places
 * */
class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Loading Places..."));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

        try {

            String types = "bus_station";
            double radius = 1000;
            nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(),
                    gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                 * */
                // Get json response status
                String status = nearPlaces.status;

                // Check for all possible status
                if(status.equals("OK")){
                    // Successfully got places details
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                        // loop through each place
                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                            // Place name
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);


                            // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                            placesListItems.add(map);
                        }
                        // list adapter
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, placesListItems,
                                R.layout.list_item,
                                new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                                        R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                        // Adding data into listview
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
                else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                    // Zero results found
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Near Places",
                            "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                            false);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured.",
                            false);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the AsyncTask in a proper way. The usage of arguments are wrong.

1. You have to return something from doInbackground to onPostExecute method, maybe an array of addresses, because your doinbackground was just trying to download something, while you're already accessing the data. Try to read the stack trace, it's pointing to your 217 line of code and also on your runOnUiThread. On line 217 your variable is null.
2. onPostExecute is already a uiThread method, so no runnables should be implemented there. Just right your code smth like this:

> ```
>  protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addressList) {
>     for (Address address : addressList) {
>         YourActivity.this.displayAddressLines(address);
>     }
>  }
> ```

Comment: Hi PAcan, thank you for the reply. I've tried according to what you said, I wasn't anble to get it working.. it crashes. I've uploaded the initial project, link; please take a quick look at it; http://www.reunioni.com/tests/Get2Food.zip (map libraries can be found in libs folder)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the wrong http client, that was already deprecated and it's not downloading anything. Your array "nearPlaces" is null. Try to use standard android http client. Read this:

http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

For AsyncTask usage: you should change your code smth like this:

```
class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, PlacesList>
{

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        /*
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Loading Places..."));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show(); */

    }

    @Override
    protected PlacesList doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground");

        // creating Places class object
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();
        try {
            // Separeate your place types by PIPE symbol "|"
            // If you want all types places make it as null
            // Check list of types supported by google
            //
            String types = "bus_station";

            // Radius in meters
            double radius = 1609.34; // 1609.34 meters = 1 mile

            // get nearest places
            nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(),
                    gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);
            Log.d(TAG, nearPlaces.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nearPlaces;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * and show the data in UI
     * Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI from background
     * thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PlacesList nearPlaces1) {
        super.onPostExecute(nearPlaces1);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute");

        nearPlaces=nearPlaces1;


        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        /*
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { */


        /**
         * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
         * */
        // Get json response status
        String status = nearPlaces.status;

        // Check for all possible status
        if(status.equals("OK"))
        {

            // Successfully got places details
            if (nearPlaces.results != null)
            {

                // loop through each place
                for (Place p : nearPlaces.results)
                {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Place reference won't display in listview - it will be hidden
                    // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                    map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                    // Place name
                    map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);


                    // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                    placesListItems.add(map);
                }

                // list adapter
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, placesListItems,
                        R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                        R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                // Adding data into listview
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
        else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
            // Zero results found
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Near Places",
                    "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                    false);
        }
        else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
        {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                    "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                    false);
        }
        else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
        {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                    "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                    false);
        }
        else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
        {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                    "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                    false);
        }
        else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
        {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                    "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                    false);
        }
        else
        {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                    "Sorry error occured.",
                    false);
        }
    }
}
```

It's just about using the right parameters.

About your custom objects: in android they should implement Parcelable interface, not standard java Serializable.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Good luck!

Comment: Hi PAcan, thanks a lot for your solution, async task makes more sense now. But I'm still getting following error: NullPointerException; MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:221)
mapplace.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)

Comment: I'm debugging it, the application dies when it tries to search places with HTTPRequestFactory, but it shows it dies in the onPostExecute because it's being executed in that part. 

[code]
            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));

[/code]

Comment: Please, read my answer once again. You're using the wrong old client to connect to the internet and find your places array. Please try these ones: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html